# Google Adwords API ReportDefinition different responses for the same request

Tags: php, google-ads-api

As you can understand by the title I receive different response at the same request using Google Adwords API ReportDefinition.
I request a CSV report and Cost and Clicks change for the same campaign!

Comment: Are you requesting data for a time range that includes the current day?

Comment: Yes..but it's the first time I find trouble. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Well if you include the current day then I would expect the numbers to be different from call to call as your campaign is accumulating impresssions and clicks. So I don't think that's "fixable".

Comment: Ok, sorry..I know the amount increases during the day. I mean sometimes in the report miss a line (the most important) related to the active ADS group and I don't know why..